# Can Linear SVM be used to build a lexicon for a specific set of categories?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, scikit-learn

I want to build a lexicon for a specific set of educational set of categories. For example: Math, Medical and Economics. So I've manually collected 150 websites per category.

I used the Python library Scikit-learn to implement the algorithm. I basically just followed the [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) from scikit-learn but instead of using their data, I've used the websites that I collected. This is a supervised task so after preprocessing (removing stop words, using TfidfVectorizer), I fed it to the LinearSVC model of scikit-learn.

What I realized is that LinearSVC weighted each word in the input vector for each category. Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

So my question is, can this be considered a lexicon for Math, Medical and Economics?

Comment: Yes. You can use it for that.

Comment: @Aaron Alright thanks! If you'd like, you can expound your answer below (for example by adding references, etc..) and I would gladly accept it as the answer.